# Find index of element with jq

Tags: json, jq

Given a json array like:

```
["a","b","c"]
```

I want to get the index of `"b"` (here, this index is 1).

How would I proceed using `jq`?

Comment: you can do just  `index("b")` or `map(.=="b") | index(true)`

Comment: Oh, you're right, I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `to_entries`, we can pair indices with values:

```
$ echo '["a","b","c"]' | jq 'to_entries[]'
{
  "key": 0,
  "value": "a"
}
{
  "key": 1,
  "value": "b"
}
{
  "key": 2,
  "value": "c"
}
```

So this works:

```
echo '["a","b","c"]' | jq 'to_entries[] | select(.value == "a") | .key'
```